# show Warning messege when entering area by corelocation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

how can i
 show Warning messege when entering area by useing corelocation framework
Before entering the area a short distance

Comment: region monitoring + uilocalnotification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Region Monitoring works great if you're looking for accuracy like 1000 meters:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

If You're looking for higher accuracy, like i.e. 10 meters you'll need to poll CoreLocation updates and write your own method for checking distance to POI's.